# Welcome to nginx! page keeps on showing

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, plesk

I was able to use nginx to be a reverse proxy in apache with Plesk 10.4.4

I followed this tutorial for your preference:
http://gudym.net/plesk-nginx.html

Now, everything worked after many instructions followed how to do it in net.
Now, the problem is that: if I typed mydomain.com, this page shows up:
Welcome to nginx!

but I when typed mydomain.com:8080 or mydomain.com/index.html everything's fine and it shows the real html files I have. Even when I turn it back the apache to listen to port 80 then stop nginx running, the Welcome to nginx! page still shows up. Tried to do yum remove nginx and made sure nginx is not installed anymore yet the page Welcome to nginx! still shows up

FYI: I use Cent OS 6.1 64bit

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance! I am getting crazy with this error already!

Comment: Sounds like the apache process listening on port 80 is perhaps 'pointing' to the same root dir that nginx used, this may not have been removed by yum so will still be served, have you checked this? Also before you removed nginx it sounds as though you have `yourdomain` set up on port 8080 if you didn't want to specify the port in the url you should have set it up on port 80 which is fine to use the same port/ip, provided you alias you can run serveral sites on same port/ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little late but I had the same issue and solved it by doing the following in my nginx site configuration file:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```